# Extracting value from subquery to main query

Tags: sql

I'm having a difficult time extracting a value from a subquery.

Suppose I have following tables:

**D( fid , pid , r ),**

**F( fid , t , j )**

I need f.j from a subquery below at the first select.

```
SELECT pid -- Here I need f.j to show up
FROM D
WHERE r='something' AND fid IN
            (
            SELECT f2.fid
            FROM F f2, 
                (
                SELECT f.j, COUNT(*) -- I need f.j above
                FROM F f
                GROUP BY f.j
                HAVING COUNT(*) >=2
                ) f
            WHERE f.j = f2.j
            )
GROUP BY pid
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide us the table structure and some example data in sql friddle?

Comment: are you using SQL Server? MySQL? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no sample data it is not clear what should be the output, still you can try the following but this is not optimized.

```
SELECT  pid ,
        t.j -- Here I need f.j to show up
FROM    D
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT f2.fid ,
                            f2.j
                     FROM   F f2 ,
                            ( SELECT    f.j 
                              FROM      F f
                              GROUP BY  f.j
                              HAVING    COUNT(*) >= 2
                            ) f
                     WHERE  f.j = f2.j
                   ) t ON D.fid = t.fid
WHERE   r = 'something'
GROUP BY pid, t.j
HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Can you please suggest in solving this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369874/how-to-select-the-value-from-sub-query-result

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temp table in this form **T( pid , j )**.  Then you can insert all the pid and f.j data separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.pid, f.j, count(f.*) as count
FROM d inner join f
on d.fid = p.fid
WHERE d.r = "something"
GROUP by d.pid, f.j
HAVING count(f.*) >=- 2
```

Note that I haven't tried this query out. However, I guess this is how it should be looked at.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
SELECT D.pid, E.j
FROM D
INNER JOIN (SELECT f1.j
        FROM F f2
        INNER JOIN 
            (
            SELECT f.j, COUNT(*)
            FROM F f
            GROUP BY f.j
            HAVING COUNT(*) >=2
            ) f1
        ON f1.j = f2.j
       ) E
 ON D.fid = E.fid
 WHERE r='something' AND fid IN
        (
        SELECT f2.fid
        FROM F f2, 
            (
            SELECT f.j, COUNT(*) -- I need f.j above
            FROM F f
            GROUP BY f.j
            HAVING COUNT(*) >=2
            ) f
        WHERE f.j = f2.j
        )
 GROUP BY D.pid
 HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```