# how to select the value from sub query result

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have the following 4 tables mentioned below and trying to extract the value **ACC_NUMBER** from sub query, Please help me with optimized correct syntax

```
ACCOUNT TABLE
-------------------------
|ACC_NUMBER  |  ACC_NAME|
-------------------------

ACCOUNT_DETAILS TABLE
---------------------------------
|ACC_NUMBER |DEAL_NUMBER|DEAL_TYPE|
---------------------------------

DEALS TABLE
------------------------------------
|DEAL_NUMBER |DEAL_TYPE|DEP_NUMBER |
------------------------------------

DEPARTMENT TABLE
------------------------
|DEP_NUMBER  | DEP_NAME |
------------------------

SELECT 
D.DEAL_NUMBER,
D.D_TYPE,
DP.DEPARTMENT_NUMBER 
FROM 
DEALS D , DEPARTMENT DP
WHERE 
D.DEP_NUMBER = DP.DEP_NUMBER
AND D.DEAL_NUMBER NOT IN
                 (SELECT ACD.DEAL_NUMBER
                    FROM ACCOUNT_DETAILS ACD, ACCOUNT AC
                   WHERE AC.ACC_NUMBER = ACD.ACC_NUMBER
                        AND DEAL_TYPE = 'XXXX'
                         AND ACD.DEAL_NUMBER = D.DEAL_NUMBER)
```

Comment: Before anything else you must use `ANSI` sql join rather than this old join technique

Comment: If you are using "D.DEAL_NUMBER NOT IN" that means that records join is not present in ACCOUNT and ACCOUNT_DETAILS table, How could you expect to get ACC_NUMBER for that particular deals?

Comment: I am trying to extract the ACC_NUMBER with some alteration in the current syntax , But i want the ACC_NUMBER in the result

Answer (score 1):

> Hi, If you are using `D.DEAL_NUMBER NOT IN` that means that records
>   join is not present in ACCOUNT and ACCOUNT_DETAILS table, You will
>   never get  ACC_NUMBER for that particular deals?
>
> If you are ready to do some alteration in the current syntax, You can
>   play with joins to get ACC_NUMBER in your query result:

Example:

```
SELECT 
D.DEAL_NUMBER,
D.D_TYPE,
ACD.ACC_NUMBER,
DP.DEPARTMENT_NUMBER 
FROM 
DEALS D 
join DEPARTMENT DP
on D.DEP_NUMBER = DP.DEP_NUMBER
left join ACCOUNT_DETAILS ACD
on ACD.DEAL_NUMBER = D.DEAL_NUMBER
join ACCOUNT AC AC.ACC_NUMBER = ACD.ACC_NUMBER
WHERE DEAL_TYPE = 'XXXX'
             AND ACD.DEAL_NUMBER = D.DEAL_NUMBER
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , The earlier requirement was to select the deal_number which is not associated with account_details table , Now the new requirement is to select the deal_number and the account_number

Comment: Am thinking can we achieve this by creating function?

Comment: why to create function if you can achieve it using simple queries.

Comment: If you want only deal_number which are associated with account_details table you can use inner join instead of left join in above query.